# What causes "Downloading proxy script..." | Any cons for disabling "Automatically detect settings" | Google Chrome

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, proxy

Many times I installed/reinstalled Windows 10 on different devices.
Every time after install, Chrome works perfect without issues.
But after a few hours/days it causes the "Downloading proxy script..." issue.

Everyone know how to fix this. Just by unchecking "Automatically detect settings" in Internet Proxy Settings.

1. But why? What are the causes?
2. Is this correct way to uncheck "Automatically detect settings"? What is the perfect way to resolve this issue?

I tried everything- Reinstalling Chrome, Reset Internet Settings, Network Reset,... nothing worked.

Surprisingly, I noticed that this issue is resolved after 'install and uninstall' when trying the trial of "NordVPN".
(maybe, did it fixed some corrupted system setting?)

And this issue only happens for Chrome on Windows, Mozilla Firefox and Edge are safe, also Chrome on Linux Ubuntu is safe.

By the way, from a few days Chrome pages are loading slow and saying "Resolving host..."

Thank you. And I'm hoping a solid-professional answer.